# help drawing a plane cutting a cone

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am trying to draw the following figure with 3d Tikz but with little success.

My codes will be posted here after some corrections.

I am a newbie and would appreciate any hint from the forum.

Many thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Shelmy

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you already have some code as you say you do, please post it here so that people don't need to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is to give you a start. You can use `tikz-3dplot` to obtain orthographic projections of some 3d setting.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=stealth,declare function={xmax=30;},
line join=bevel]
 \draw[->] (-2,0,0) coordinate (A) -- (1,0,0) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
 \draw (-2,-5,0) coordinate (P) plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:xmax] 
 (-2,{-5*cos(\x)},{5*sin(\x)})
 coordinate(p1);
 \fill[name path=plane,gray,opacity=0.3] (-2.2,{-5*cos(xmax)},-0.5) --
  (2.2,{-5*cos(xmax)},-0.5) -- (2.2,{-5*cos(xmax)},3) -- (-2.2,{-5*cos(xmax)},3) -- cycle;
 \path[name path=left] (P) -- (A);
 \draw[name intersections={of=left and plane,by={B,B'}}]
  (P) -- (B') (-2,{-5*cos(xmax)},0) coordinate(B) -- (A) -- (p1) --(B);
 \path[name path=right] (P) -- (0,0,0) coordinate (O);
 \draw[name intersections={of=right and plane,by={C,C'}}]
  (P) -- (C') 
  ({-2+2*(1-cos(xmax))},{-5*cos(xmax)},0) coordinate (C) -- (O) -- (p1) -- (C)
  (O) -- (0,{{-5*cos(xmax)}},0) coordinate (O');
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[gray!30] (B') -- (B) (C') -- (C); 
 \end{scope}
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,1,0) node[pos=1.3]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,1) node[pos=1.3]{$z$};
 \foreach \X in {O,P,A,B,C}
 {\node[inner sep=1pt,circle,fill,label=below:$\X$] at (\X){};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]